# How can i get the child values from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get values from `Firebase` Database and set them to text view. My database has multiple child like in image. I want to get the Phone and Address values from it. How can I get them? I am new to Android and I have tried multiple answers here, but failed. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: Here is how my DB screenshot]

Comment: First you should learn how Firebase with Android works because you will probably face many problems if you don't know about it  please watch this tutorials https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt

Comment: Thank you, I have already followed some of the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String address = ds.child("Address").getValue(String.class);
            String phone = ds.child("Phone").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", address + " / " + phone);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And this is the code to get the address from a single user:

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String address = dataSnapshot.child("Address").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", address);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But there is a problem. I want it for single user, It is calling all users address. I want it as per the user Id.

Comment: I have one more question, how can I delete the child? I mean if i delete a account, it should also remove the child, the one with user id which contains address and phone. Can you please help me this also?

Comment: Just use `removeValue()` method directly on the desired reference like this: `rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).removeValue();`